# SSH with public/private key to iMac fails

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, rsa

I'm trying to connect to my iMac (server) from my macbook (client) on my LAN. Both have Mac OS X 10.6.4. Server running on a new clean install of the OS. When just activating `Remote Login` in `System Preferences` everything works fine. But when setting up ssh to only work with public/private key I get the following error messages from the server log depending on if I use a rsa passphrase or not:

- With passphrase (case 1):

  `PAM: user account has expired for <myServerUserName> from 192.168.X.X via 192.168.X.Y`
- Without passphrase (case 2):

  `Failed publickey for <myServerUserName> from 192.168.X.X port AAAAA ssh2`

This is my setup algorithm:

- Create a private and public key on client with command `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. In case 1 I also set a passphrase.
- Move the `id_rsa.pub` to the server path `/Users/<myServerUserName>/.ssh/`
- In this folder I execute `cat id_rsa.pub > authorized_keys`
- Making sure `Remote Login` isn't active, I now execute `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d` on the server.
- Back on the client I now type `ssh -v -v -v <myServerUserName>@192.168.X.Y` and get prompted to accept RSA key fingerprint. This is NOT the same fingerprint as the one from when I created the private/public key (should it be?). I accept.
- Depending on case:

  - CASE 1: Client gets halted for password and the response is `permission denied` even though correct password is given. Back on the server I can read the error message I stated above for case 1: `PAM: user account has expired...`
  - CASE 2: Client gets message `Connection closed by 192.168.X.Y`. Back on the server I can read the error message I stated above for case 2: `Failed publickey...`

What could possibly cause this?

Comment: Is there a reason you're starting `sshd` via the command-line?  Have you modified `/etc/sshd_config` or `/etc/pam.d/sshd` ?  Your "CASE 1" example looks like the user you're trying to connect with isn't valid.

Comment: Have you double checked the permissions / mode of the authorized_keys file?

Comment: @medina: Yeah, I wanted to see the log. I've tried starting ssh from `System Preferences/Sharing` and the results are the same. I have tried modifying `/etc/sshd_config`, but I haven't made any changes to `/etc/pam.d/sshd` yet. I'm not 100% sure what to do, I'm kinda new to this.

@ForgeMan: Do you mean by just typing `ls -l`? What permissions should be set?

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of hints, I have had to set the identity file (rsa private/public key) as filename identity and identity.pub on MacOSX.  I am pretty sure this is the default name.

You can specify the filename when using the ssh command, by using 'ssh -i /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa user@host' in your case and this should always work.  It is the best way to determine if the default filename is the problem.